# How to get the path from root to a given node on a arbitrary tree?

Tags: java, tree, depth-first-search

I have this tree:

```
Harry(root)
Jane
    Joe
    Diane
        George
            Jill
                Carol
        Mary
    Mark
Bill
    Grace
```

I've extended the code in [this page](http://www.quesucede.com/page/show/id/java-tree-implementation#tree-class)

with this function that uses the *depth-first search*.

```
public static int path(Tree t, String root, String n)
{
    // Default traversal strategy is 'depth-first'
    int counter = 0;
    Iterator<Node> depthIterator = t.iterator(root);
    while (depthIterator.hasNext()) {
        Node node = depthIterator.next();
        if(node.getIdentifier().compareTo(n)==0)
        {
            System.out.println("Distance from " + root +" to " + n + " " + counter);
            return counter;
        }
        counter++;
        System.out.println(node.getIdentifier());
    }
    return 0;
}
```

My final goal is to find the length of a path between the root and a given node. When I run this function the distance from root and Joe, and, the distance from root and Diane (which are siblings) is different because it counts the steps of the depth-first search.
Is this approach wrong or is a way to fix it?

Comment: Is it important for you to use the Iterator of the depth first search? I think the iterator can be problematic because he jumps in the tree (you could for example be at a depth of 5 and the next node is a child of the root (depth 1)). I think writing your own depth first search including a depth count would be easier than using the existing Iterator.

Comment: If you know the node, couldn't you push it into a stack then go to its parent and push into a stack until you are at the root, after which pop the whole stack and have the path you want?

Comment: @VenomFangs It seems like the Node class doesn't have a parent (the Node's don't know theire parent). They only know theire children.

Comment: What about a function that returns the depth of the node even without using the depth first search?

Comment: @user840718, when you are adding the nodes if you have a reference to the parent, you can pull its depth and add one to it. If you do that for every add, then you'll have the depth you need, whenever you need.

Answer (score 0):

Your use of counter for finding the depth is incorrect. In the code that you have shown you are only counting the items in the iterator.

You need to make your path() method be recursively called and pass the depth value as a parameter for the method. And increment the depth value for each recursive call.